# How to correctly update state with multiple event handlers in parent component (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have all the state for an app in one parent component. It renders multiple child components, two of which contain dropdown menus. The parent component has event handlers for both of those dropdown menu components, which are supposed to update state. The first handler does correctly update state, but the second doesn't. I *assume* that this has something to do with `setState()` being asynchronous, but I don't know for sure. What's the fix for this? Should the second handler be part of a lifecycle event? Something else?

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SubList from './SubList';
import StopList from './StopList';
import { IsDelayN, IsDelayS } from './IsDelay';

class SubCheck extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selectedSub: null,
        selectedStop: null,
        stops: [],
    };
    this.handleSubSelect = this.handleSubSelect.bind(this);
    this.handleStopSelect = this.handleStopSelect.bind(this);
    }

    // We want the user to be able to select their specific subway
    // stop, so obviously a different array of stops needs to be 
    // loaded for each subway. We're getting those from utils/stops.json.
    handleSubSelect(event) {
        var stopData = require('../utils/stops');
        var stopsArray = [];
        var sub = event.target.value
        for (var i = 0; i < stopData.length; i++) {
            var stop = stopData[i];

            if (String(stop.stop_id).charAt(0) === sub) {
                stopsArray.push(stop.stop_name);
            }
        }
        this.setState(() => {
            return {
                selectedSub: sub,
                stops: stopsArray
            }
        });
    }

    handleStopSelect(event) {
        this.setState({selectedStop: event.target.value});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <SubList onSubSelect={this.handleSubSelect}/>
                <StopList stops={this.state.stops} onStopSelect={this.handleStopSelect}/>
                <IsDelayN sub={this.state.selectedSub} stop={this.state.selectedStop}/>
                <IsDelayS sub={this.state.selectedSub} stop={this.state.selectedStop}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SubCheck;
```

Comment: I think it's not re-rendering, since none of it's props have changed, so why should it?   Maybe send in stop={this.state.selectedStop}... then when the selectedStop changes, the component will actually re-render?

Comment: @billjamesdev What I need to do, though, is send in that array that's currently in stops. That will become options in a dropdown menu in a child prop, then when one of those options is clicked, that's supposed to update selectedStop in state.

Comment: yes, but you don't send that selectedStop into the SubList... How is the list of SubList options specified?  Does it change when a Stop is selected? and if it doesn't, why would it need to re-render?

Comment: Is `handleStopSelect(event) {` ever getting called? Place `console.log` inside of this method to see is it getting executed.